# Migrar SharePoint 2007 para SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint

Olá,
Preciso migrar sites do sharepoint 2007 diretamente para o sharepoint 2013.
Posso faze-lo diretamente pulando o sharepoint 2010 e pelo método de exportação da base de conteúdo?

Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Não há migração direta, vc tem de migrar 2007> 2010 > 2013.
Já quebrei muito a cabeça nesta migração...
Boa sorte..